# SBS2011 Detailed Network Report

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-sbs, windows-sbs-2011

I have configured an SBS2011 Server to e-mail me a weekly 'Detailed Network Report' (saw it while configuring a daily e-mailed Back Up report).

Within the Report there is lots of info regarding all the Roles on the server (Security, Updates, Back Up etc).

Under `E-Mail Usage and Mailbox Sizes` the following is shown:

[image]

Now I know these users are sending much more than 1 e-mail a week! So what exactly is this report showing? E-mails within the last 24 hours?

How do I go about configuring the Report to show me e-mail statistics for the last week/day/whatever?

Comment: I have just checked one of my SBS 2011 servers, same thing is happening. Bug.......?

Comment: Perhaps there is a scheduled task that needs to be run periodically to gather these statistics